# Lists within Lists, Loops within loops Automate the Boring Stuff

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

So i am trying to work my way though the Automate the Boring Stuff book and class but I am having a terrible time trying to figure out the second practice question at the end of chapter 4.

The problem asks to copy this

grid = 
[['.','.','.','.','.','.'],
['.','0','0','.','.','.'],
['0','0','0','0','.','.'],
['0','0','0','0','0','.'],
['.','0','0','0','0','0'],
['0','0','0','0','0','.'],
['0','0','0','0','.','.'],
['.','0','0','.','.','.'],
['.','.','.','.','.','.']]

And write a code that prints it out like this

..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....

So I was able to figure out how to call the list within a list values and print the heart sideways using this code:

```
grid = [['.','.','.','.','.','.'],
    ['.','0','0','.','.','.'],
    ['0','0','0','0','.','.'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0','.'],
    ['.','0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0','.'],
    ['0','0','0','0','.','.'],
    ['.','0','0','.','.','.'],
    ['.','.','.','.','.','.']]
    

for x in grid:
    for y in x:
        print(y,end='')
    print('\n')
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to print it the right way. I understand that I need to call the values at the 0 index within each list in the whole list first, then the 1 index and so on.

I looked at other answers and adjusted my code to this:

```py
for x in range(len(grid[0])):
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[x][y],end='')
    print('\n')
```

Initially I had it without range(len()) but it gave me an error saying indices must be integers(which is fixed using the len function i assume because the len function returns an actual integer, right?). Now I am getting an error that my list is out of range. I have been trying to figure this out on my own for a few hours now and I am just not understanding at all and trying to quell my frustration. Can anyone help me out? Ive seen some other answers with some more advanced methods used to complete the practice but I am really trying to grasp these concepts I am learning now and just the basics in general so I am only looking for suggestions that involve really the simplest methods of lists, and loops. Thank you guys and I can add more information if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should swap the looping variables during printing (effectively rotating the print).

```py
for x in range(len(grid[0])):
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[y][x],end='')
    print() # Removed '\n' here because it printed two lines (end='\n' by default)
```

This works because the outer loop (`x`) is through each column, and the inner loop (`y`) is through each row. So by printing in that order you effectively rotate the image.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I did have my code like that at one point but it prints the heart out sideways. Turns out all I had to do was switch the x and y in the print statement and that fixed the error and it prints correctly. Thank you so much for your answer!!

Comment: Ah my mistake, I couldn't tell in my printout it *wasn't* rotated. Glad you got it figured out, I have since updated my answer so it's accurate for the question. @sarah.andromeda315